# Android won't respect card_view attributes

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have the following in an xml file called item_school.xml, and I'm inflating it to populate my recyclerview. The recycler view respects the android:layout* attributes and changes the layout spacing between cards when I change these attributes, but when I add any card_view attributes the view does not change.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"

    card_view:cardCornerRadius="50dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="50dp">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="24dp"
        android:paddingRight="24dp"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_school_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimary"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_school_address"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorTertiary"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

I bumped up the radius and elevation to 50dp, and even tried changing the background to black but the view still looks the same (default background, corners and shadow). It seems like the default values are overriding the ones I have in the xml. What do I need to do?

EDIT: Target SDK:23, Min SDK:15

Comment: Dont use the Linear Layout inside the CardView

Comment: @Sunny I'm targeting SDK 23, with minimum set at 15.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're using wrong namespace for the cardview.
Try to use :

```
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

instead of

```
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/relativelayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardview1"
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorfont_white"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">



            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/info_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/profile"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="13dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="@+id/info_text"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="@string/content"
                android:id="@+id/tvpmpcontent"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="13dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/info_text"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/info_text"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/info_text" />


        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It seems to be incomplete.. From what I can tell you're suggesting I use a relative layout instead but the linear layout displays the textviews on the card fine. It's the card itself I'm trying to style.